# How to create a pdf with watermark in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, watermark

I'm developing an web application, I have a tables and I want to create, each table as a pdf with watermark. I am trying to create pdf with watermark using jquery. Can someone help me? thank you.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/). --- Please read [ask].

Answer (score 4):

You are able to add watermark to pdf at back end. You could use [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/),[itextpdf](http://itextpdf.com/) to add watermark.
Just view my project [pdfProject](https://github.com/caiyongji/PdfProject), you could add watermark easily.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with just jQuery - it's not meant to export PDFs.

You could use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), and when passing through the div or table you just set the background equal to your watermark.

If you want to preserve text content it won't be particularly easy. Otherwise, you can just convert to image and overlay an opaque version of your watermark with any PDF library.